# Passing data though multiple activities (while one gets destroyed)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I'm building my first Android app in Android Studio (with Java) and I need some help understanding how to pass data through multiple activities.

The setup of affected classes/activities is this:

1. MainActivity: Opens a dialog called AddDialog (by creating a new Instance of it).
2. AddDialog (extends AppCompatDialogFragment): A dialog that has some buttons. One of them launches a class called BarcodeScanActivity (using intent).
3. BarcodeScanActivity: Simple activity that scan QR codes.

I want to pass the list of QR codes scanned by BarcodeScanActivity (I store them in a String Array) to MainActivity in order to use them, although BarcodeScanActivity is launched from the dialog that gets destroyed once buttons are clicked. Because of that I'm unable to set some startActivityForResult on the dialog and chain the result (onActivityResult) back to the MainActivity.

Also since MainActivity launches the AddDialog by creating an instance, I can't set a startActivityForResult there too.

I have tried adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT while launching BarcodeScanActivity from AddDialog, hoping that the result from BarcodeScanActivity will be forwarded back to MainActivity where I have created an onActivityResult method since AddDialog gets destroyed, but I don't know if that is even supposed to work as AddDialog is "launched" by a new instance of it, and not by using an intent.

I have thought about using broadcasts as a last resort, although I read that they are insecure, unreliable and not supposed to be used for passing that kind of data.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: i'm struggling to understand this `although BarcodeScanActivity is launched from the dialog that gets destroyed once buttons are clicked` could you please add code to your question

Comment: @a_local_nobody Well my code is a mess since I was trying a ton of things in order to debug this issue I'm having, I'll add some snippets later today.

What I mean with the quoted phrase is that once a button is pressed on the dialog, dialog closes, and because of that, It seems like I can't have a startActivityForResult / onActivityResult pair in order to pass the data from BarcodeScanActivity back to the AddDialog and then to MainActivity.

If there is any way to directly send data from BarcodeScanActivity to MainActivity that would be ideal but I don't think it's possible...

Comment: it's a bit hard to answer without seeing code, but i think your thought process might be your biggest problem here, i think your _dialog_ should be telling your _activity_ whether or not to start the other activity.

Comment: @a_local_nobody That's a great idea actually, thanks. I'll try signaling the MainActivity when button on dialog is pressed so that MainActivity can start the BarcodeScanActivity using startActivityForResult in order to get the data back!

Comment: i understand you're completely new to android, we've all been there, but once you learn a few architectures and practice a bit, you'll realise that dialogs don't ever _do_ anything, except for showing content. usually, dialogs make use of callbacks/events to tell their containing activity/fragment to then do something.

Comment: @a_local_nobody You're right, this is my first Android app and I'm still experimenting with what activity/layout/fragment/etc I need to use and when. I ended up setting an intent from the BarcodeScanActivity directly to MainActivity passing the data I wanted. I was originally thinking this is a bad idea since it was launching the MainActivity on top of the existing one, but I found about AndroidManifest's declaration `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and the use of `onNewIntent` method that eliminate that issue. Which confirms the "wrong thought process" you initially mentioned :)

Comment: awesome, happy to hear